# Cancel the flow and go back to the first node in botpress

Tags: typescript, chatbot, botpress

We are using botpress for chat bot where all flow are working fine, but we need to implement one functionality that handles the cancel. We created a nlu and assigned a flow to handle it but still flow is not being handled properly.

```
  /**
   * Small description of your action
   * @title The title displayed in the flow editor
   * @category Custom
   * @author Your_Name
   * @param {string} name - An example string variable
   * @param {any} value - Another Example value
   */
  const myAction = async (name, value) => {
    await bp.dialog.pop()
  }

  return myAction(args.name, args.value)
```

Any help or guidance is deeply appreciated.